# Multiple Azure Web App Instances - Inconsistent DB Queries / Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App with autoscaling configured with a minimum of 2 instances. Database is SQL Azure.

User will make changes to the data e.g. edit a product's price. The change will make it to the database and I can see it in SSMS. However, after user refreshes the page, the data may or may not get updated.

My current theory is something to do with having multiple instances of the web app, because if I turn off autoscale and just have 1 instance, the issue is gone.

I haven't configured any sort of caching in Azure at all.

Comment: Are you using AJAX calls or post back ? You said you haven't configured any cache in Azure, but do you confirm that you do not have cache on the MVC app itself (like ouput caching or something ?). Also, have you disabled ARR affinity cookie ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what is happening is the data may or may not appear because it is stored in memory on the worker server (at least temporarily). When you have multiple worker servers, a different one may serve the request, in which case that server would not have the value in memory. The solution is to make sure that your application's code is re-fetching the value from the database in every case.

Azure Web Apps has some built in protection against this, called the ARR affinity cookie. Essentially each request has a cookie which keeps sessions "sticky". i.e. if a worker server is serving requests to a certain user, that user should receive subsequent requests from that server as well. This is the default behavior, but you may have disabled it. See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: ARR affinity cookie was turned off.